# Apply filter in Elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to apply filter after aggregate query. For example, with the below aggregate query, I want to get only those entries where we have all the windows.

**Note:** we do not have to use *include* because it uses regular expression which is time consuming and we cannot ignore the case.

Query:

```
GET /record_new/_search
{"size":0, "aggs" : {
        "software_tags" : {
            "terms" : {

                "field" : "software_tags.keyword",
                  "size" : 100


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took": 77,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 5706542,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "software_tags": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 5514,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 581800,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Microsoft Windows",
          "doc_count": 70641
        },
        {
          "key": "Bitcoin",
          "doc_count": 35423
        },
        {
          "key": "Linux",
          "doc_count": 33230
        },
        {
          "key": "ICQ",
          "doc_count": 21934
        },
        {
          "key": "PHP",
          "doc_count": 20562
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows XP",
          "doc_count": 19720
        },
        {
          "key": "Android (operating system)",
          "doc_count": 17774
        },
        {
          "key": "C++",
          "doc_count": 14792
        },
        {
          "key": "Pretty Good Privacy",
          "doc_count": 14307
        },
        {
          "key": "Tor (anonymity network)",
          "doc_count": 14110
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to do filter as well but I am not getting incorrect output. In output we are getting **linux** as well. I don't know what is happening here.

```
GET /record_new/_search
{"size":0, "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": 
        { "term": { "software_tags": "windows"   }}

    }
  }, "aggs" : {
        "software_tags" : {
            "terms" : {

                "field" : "software_tags.keyword",
                  "size" : 10


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "took": 11,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 93181,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "software_tags": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 1640,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 171831,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Microsoft Windows",
          "doc_count": 70641
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows XP",
          "doc_count": 19720
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows 7",
          "doc_count": 12692
        },
        {
          "key": "Linux",
          "doc_count": 12311
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Vista",
          "doc_count": 10172
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows NT",
          "doc_count": 5417
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Registry",
          "doc_count": 5055
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows 8",
          "doc_count": 4829
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows 2000",
          "doc_count": 4738
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows 10",
          "doc_count": 4611
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you don't filter for it before the aggregation? So you only aggregate those that have Windows in the software_tags?

Comment: @MrSimple I have updated the question with filter. I am getting incorrect response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, it should look for records with windows in the software_tag:

```
{
  "size":0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "software_tags: *windows* AND NOT *linux* AND NOT *<next OS name to exclude>*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, "aggs" : {
        "software_tags" : {
            "terms" : {

                "field" : "software_tags.keyword",
                  "size" : 10


            }
        }
    }
}
```

It might be a bit slower than the usual queries but thats because of the wildcard character in the query.

Comment: Are you using kibana too? If yes try this in Discover menu: software_tag: xwindowsx (wildcards in place of the x marks)

Comment: Sry, there was a typo in it, I wrote software_tag instead of software_tags

Comment: It is working but it is still returning irrelevant responses as well.
If you see the output I have mentioned using the filter. We are getting 'Linux ' as wellin the output.
Any idea why is it so?

Comment: I tweaked the query, but since I don't have the data I'm not sure it helps. Hope it works.

Comment: I think the query you sent is correct if software tags is not an array. software_tags with values=["linux","Windows 7", "Windows XP"] is also coming in the solution because we have windows in the array. Is there any way to get inly that value from array which matches the regular exression

Comment: I changed the query, I made some minor tests before and it worked for me. I excluded Linux for you as an example but you can go on and list other unwanted systems too. This obviously works only for a limited and known set of items and would cause a problem for a "Windows Linux 3.14" system, because it should be listed but wouldn't. So this solution has limited capabilities but in this case it might just be enough.

Comment: Wow that is a good workaround! But we can't keep on adding 'and Not' in the query. Because we don't have just OS in the software_tags array.
Do you think that query="*windows*" should even return Linux in response?    It returns linux because software_tags=["linux","iOS","Android","windows"] has windows in the array and the mapping for software_tags is defined as **text**.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to solve this without the workaround. I didn't do research, this is rather a gut feeling. The workaround can only use "any positive" matches and not "all positive" matches because of the query_string. And we need that because windows (or anything needed) can appear in different varieties. So if we don't want something, we have to exclude. Or at least I don't think there is a way to check every element of an array.

Comment: Can we do a subquery on this to fix this problem? I will try the to fix it. Thank you for your help,