# How to do Can insensitive search in ealsticsearch (5.3.2)?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Problem This aggregation gives all 'windows' but it is case sensitive. How to do a case insensitive search?

```
GET /record_new/_search
{"size":0,
  "aggs" : {
        "software_tags" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "software_tags.keyword",
                  "include" : ".*Windows.*",
                  "size" : 10000,
                  "order" : { "_term" : "asc" }

                        }
                 }
          }

}
```

*Mapping*

```
{
  "record_new": {
    "mappings": {
      "record_new": {
        "software_tags": {
          "full_name": "software_tags",
          "mapping": {
            "software_tags": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              },
              "fielddata": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Response*

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 5706542,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "software_tags": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Bloc-notes (Windows)",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows CE",
          "doc_count": 8
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows CE 5.0",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Calculator",
          "doc_count": 33
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Communication Foundation",
          "doc_count": 43
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Contacts",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows DVD Maker",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Defender",
          "doc_count": 409
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Desktop Gadgets",
          "doc_count": 14
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Desktop Update",
          "doc_count": 33
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Display Driver Model",
          "doc_count": 64
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows DreamScene",
          "doc_count": 5
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Driver Frameworks",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Driver Kit",
          "doc_count": 12
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Driver Model",
          "doc_count": 99
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Easy Transfer",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Embedded Automotive",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Embedded CE 6.0",
          "doc_count": 7
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Embedded Compact",
          "doc_count": 361
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Embedded Compact 7",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Embedded Industry",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Essential Business Server 2008",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Essentials",
          "doc_count": 13
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Filtering Platform",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Firewall",
          "doc_count": 588
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Fundamentals for Legacy PCs",
          "doc_count": 21
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Genuine Advantage",
          "doc_count": 60
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Home Server",
          "doc_count": 7
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Image Acquisition",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Insider",
          "doc_count": 10
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Installer",
          "doc_count": 562
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Internal Database",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows IoT",
          "doc_count": 132
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Live Mail",
          "doc_count": 117
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Live Mesh",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Live Messenger",
          "doc_count": 1595
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Live OneCare",
          "doc_count": 18
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Live OneCare Safety Scanner",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Live Spaces",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Live Toolbar",
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows ME",
          "doc_count": 1055
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Management Instrumentation",
          "doc_count": 289
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Marketplace",
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Media",
          "doc_count": 168
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows Mobile",
          "doc_count": 439
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows SideShow",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Windows SteadyState",
          "doc_count": 6
        },
        {
          "key": "Центр обновления Windows",
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your mapping for this? It would be helpful to see if `software_tags` is an array, and what data type you have it as.

Comment: Added. Thanks @IanGabes

Comment: That's not a query, it's just an aggregation. What actually is the question here?

Comment: want to get all unique values where 'windows' is present. I tried a different way given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538366/apply-filter-in-elastic-search-query/48548013  but that didn't work because there were some extra data I was getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing this completely wrong. Searching and getting unique values are different things. How about the following approach?

Note, that I used slightly different settings for the aggregation and I added a `query`.

```
GET record_new/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "software_tags": {
        "value": "windows"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "software_tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "software_tags.keyword",
        "include" : ".*Windows.*",
        "size": 10000,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed the size to 10 and this is what I get:


  "aggregations": {
    "software_tags": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 321840,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "",
          "doc_count": 28
        },
        {
          "key": ".NET Framework",
          "doc_count": 116
        },
        {
          "key": ".dbf",
          "doc_count": 5
        },

Comment: If you see sum_other_doc_count = 321840 which is incorrect for windows.
Also, we are getting .NET Framework, dbf in response which is incorrect.

Comment: I have the feeling the data you posted is not everything. What you are telling me it's happening it's impossible. Is this the whole query you are using?

Comment: I have stripped few resposne data. rest are exactly same as I mentioned.

Comment: Then how could `software_tags` match `dbf` when my query is specifically looking at `windows`? It doesn't make sense. Have you tested my exact query?

Comment: Yes that is the problem.  So this what I think is happening:
software tags is an array. software_tags with values=["linux","Windows 7", "Windows XP"] so when search for windows we get all the values of the array. If there is no windows in the software_tags then no value is returned. Do I make sense to you?

Comment: Added image for the above query

Comment: So far, you haven't mentioned anything about an array of values. Of course now it does make sense

Comment: Thanks Andrei that is exact what I was looking for!

Comment: Is it also possible to sort them based on their score like the topmost should be the one with the highest matches. So, lets say if 'windows 7' matches more than 100 times while all others with windows is lesser then we should get windows 7 on the top